# Export data frames from list to txt file

Tags: r, list, dataframe, export

I have a question in exporting data frame from list into txt file. I found some solutions, but it was only for vectors. Here is one example:

```
dataframe1 <- data.frame(a= c(1,2,3,4,5), b= c(1,1,1,1,1))
dataframe2 <- data.frame(a= c(5,5,5), b= c(1,1,1))
mylist <- list(dataframe1, dataframe2)
```

I would like that the txt file looks like this:

```
$dataframe1
a b
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 1

$dataframe2
a b
5 1
5 1
5 1
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Say your list is named:

```
mylist<-structure(list(dataframe1 = structure(list(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
5), b = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame"), dataframe2 = structure(list(a = c(5, 
5, 5), b = c(1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("dataframe1", "dataframe2"
))
```

You can try:

```
con<-file("temp.csv",open="at")
Map(function(x,y) {cat(file=con,y,"\n");write.table(x,file=con,quote=FALSE,row.names=FALSE)},
     mylist,names(mylist))
close(con)
```

The above will write the files on the file `temp.csv`. You have to give names to your list if you want it to work.

Alternatively, if you are ok with the `print` method, you can just redirect the standard output to a file:

```
sink("temp.csv")
print(mylist)
sink(NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you. The alternative with print method is what I wanted. Is it possible also to remove the row names from the written file?

Comment: I found also one warning massage at the end of table: [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 3639 rows ]?!